# Sync data from component back to the calling page in ionic 5

Tags: ionic-framework, components, ionic5

In my Ionic 5 project, I have created a custom component and passing the data from a Page.

HomePage HTML:

```
<app-userItem [inUser]="user (outSync)="syncUser($event)"></app-userItem>
```

Where user is.

```
let user = {
  Name: 'Test User',
  Age: 23
}
```

Now I want if inside component `UserItem` I change the value of `Age`, it should be synced back in the Homepage user variable. It is not happening automatically.

To Achieve this I am using the `outSync` event emit method for now. My question is as I am using `[]` to pass value of parameter `inUser`, shouldn't the user variable be in sync from both sides?

Answer (score 0):

> Now I want if inside component UserItem I change the value of Age, it should be synced back in the Homepage user variable. It is not happening automatically.

I think the reason why it's not happening automatically is because Angular compares the object identity to see if something has changed, but in your case, `user === user` is `true` even after changing `user.age` because the instance is still the same.

It doesn't mean the object is not being updated – it's just that Angular doesn't know that because the instance of the object is the same so as far as Angular knows, nothing have been changed.

A better approach would be if the `UserItemComponent` only presents the data, but doesn't change it directly (which would make it a *dumb* or presentational component).

For example, if that component could change both the `name` and the `age` properties, it'd be better if it just notifies the parent that those properties should be changed, and it's the parent who updates the `user`.

```
<app-userItem 
  [inUser]="user 
  (updateAge)="updateAge($event)"
  (updateName)="updateName($event)"
></app-userItem>
```

And then the parent component would modify the data, **creating a new instance** of the object so that the child receives the update:

```
public updateAge(newAge: number): void {
  this.user = {
    ...this.user,
    age: newAge
  };
}
```